# Использование WinAPI PeekMessage()

Tags: c, winapi

Как на С с помощью `PeekMessage()` просмотреть всю очередь сообщений, не удаляя сообщения? Мне надо проверять, есть ли в очереди `WM_PAINT`, когда перед ним одно или больше `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.

Comment: Похоже на костыль. Лучше завести переменную-флаг, поднимать его при получении `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, а при `WM_PAINT` проверять и сбрасывать.

Answer (score 1):

> Мне надо проверять, есть ли в очереди WM_PAINT, когда перед ним одно или больше WM_MOUSEMOVE

Для этого можно воспользоваться функцией [GetQueueStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644940(v=vs.85).aspx) с параметром `QS_PAINT`.

Comment: но `WM_PAINT` - особое сообщение. Оно обрабатывается только когда в очереди нет других сообщений, т.е. даже если до него дошла очередь, это не значит что оно будет извлечено из очереди с очередным вызовом `GetMessage` или `PeekMessage`.