# Как получить список всех сообщений через WinApi.PeekMessage не удаляя сами сообщения?

Tags: java, c#, delphi, winapi

Как получить список всех сообщений через `PeekMessage` не удаляя сами сообщения
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagea

Есть ли такие функции как `GetCountMessage(hnd)` `GetMessageIndex(hnd)` ?

Comment: С какой целью? Какую задачу вы этим хотите решать?

Comment: @Герман Борисов дубликат сообщения не отравлять

Comment: @vegat4, [никак](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766316/how-to-use-peekmessage-to-check-all-messages-in-the-queue-without-removing-them).
Но можно проверить наличие сообщения конкретного типа (напр, `WM_CHAR`), указав фильтры и задав `wRemoveMsg = PM_NOREMOVE`. Т.е. можно в цикле пройтись по разным типам сообщений и выяснить из наличие в очереди. Ну, или придумывать другой способ коммуникации.

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/638104